# Removing SQLite Table with singular name from Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sqlite

So I'm working on migrating into a SQLite db on Rails and somehow ended up with User and Users tables. How do I remove it without removing Users?

```
  create_table "user", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "first_name"
    t.string "last_name"
    t.string "username"
    t.string "email"
    t.string "password"
    t.datetime "created_at", precision: 6, null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", precision: 6, null: false
  end

  create_table "users", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "first_name"
    t.string "last_name"
    t.string "username"
    t.string "email"
    t.string "password"
    t.datetime "created_at", precision: 6, null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", precision: 6, null: false
  end
```

Comment: ```drop_table :user``` may be?

Answer (score 0):

May not be best practice, but what seems to have solved it for me was to delete from the schema,drop the database`rails db:drop`create a new one`rails db:create` and migrate `rails db:migrate`
Good to go as far as I can tell!

Comment: Not best practice, but for a project jsut beginning or a personal one it may not matter. I would say in the future to create a rake task to move and users in the user table to the users table and then drop the table.